# C# Download Speed Asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to get the current user's network download speed. After hitting a dead end with NetworkInterfaces and all I tried a solution I found online. I edited it a bit and it works great but it's not asynchronous.

```
public static void GetDownloadSpeed(this Label lbl) 
{
    double[] speeds = new double[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int fileSize = 407; //Size of File in KB.
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (!Directory.Exists($"{CurrentDir}/tmp/speedtest"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory($"{CurrentDir}/tmp/speedtest");

        client.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r69/three.min.js"), "/tmp/speedtest/three.min.js");
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        speeds[i] = Math.Round((fileSize / (endTime - startTime).TotalSeconds));
    }

    lbl.Text = string.Format("{0}KB/s", speeds.Average());
}
```

That function is called within a timer at an interval of 2 minutes.

```
MyLbl.GetDownloadSpeed()
```

I've tried using WebClient.DownloadFileAsync but that just shows the unlimited symbol.My next try would be to use HttpClient but before I go on does anyone have a recommended way of getting the current users download speed asynchronously (without lagging the main GUI thread)?

Comment: You should include the code you tried with `DownloadFileAsync`. I suspect you caused a deadlock by calling `Result` or `Wait` somewhere on the resulting task.

Comment: Try `await Task.Run(()=> { //your code });

Comment: Thank you @PhilippeParé That worked!

Comment: @DanielKelley I made the method async and called await on it.

Comment: @PhilippeParé Can you make your comment an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was suggested you could make an async version of `GetDownloadSpeed()`:

```
    async void GetDownloadSpeedAsync(this Label lbl, Uri address, int numberOfTests)
    {
        string directoryName = @"C:\Work\Test\speedTest";
        string fileName = "tmp.dat";

        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryName))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

        timer.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; ++i)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(address, Path.Combine(directoryName, fileName), CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }

        lbl.Text == Convert.ToString(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / numberOfTests);
    }
```

WebClient class being relatively old does not have *awaitable* `DownloadFileAsync()`.

**EDITED**
As it was correctly pointed out WebClient in fact has a task-based async method DownloadFileTaskAsync(), which i advise to use. The code below can still help addressing the case when async method returning `Task` is not provided.

We can fix it with the help of `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
    public static class WebClientExtensions
    {

        public static Task DownloadFileAwaitableAsync(this WebClient instance, Uri address, 
            string fileName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

            // Subscribe for completion event
            instance.DownloadFileCompleted += instance_DownloadFileCompleted;

            // Setup cancellation
            var cancellationRegistration = cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled ? (IDisposable)cancellationToken.Register(() => { instance.CancelAsync(); }) : null;

            // Initiate asyncronous download 
            instance.DownloadFileAsync(address, fileName, Tuple.Create(tcs, cancellationRegistration));

            return tcs.Task;
        }

        static void instance_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((WebClient)sender).DownloadDataCompleted -= instance_DownloadFileCompleted;
            var data = (Tuple<TaskCompletionSource<object>, IDisposable>)e.UserState;
            if (data.Item2 != null) data.Item2.Dispose();
            var tcs = data.Item1;

            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @PeterDuniho: thanks for correction, the answer is edited to incorporate your comments.

Answer (score -1):

Try `await Task.Run(()=> { //your code });

Edit: @JustDevInc I still think you should use DownloadAsync. Task.Run(delegate) creates a new thread and you might want to avoid that. If you want, post some of your old code so we can try to fix it.

Edit: The first solution turned out to be the only one of the two working. DownloadFileAsync doesn't return task, so can't it awaited.

Comment: Try making `GetDownloadSpeed` `async`, make it return `Task` and then `await` on `DownloadFileAsync`

Comment: But there's nothing t await on? downloadFileAsync returns a void

Comment: You're right, I just checked the signature on MSDN and this method is supposed to save the resource to a local file asynchronously. It doesn't return task so it can't be awaited. I guess the first solution is the correct one!