# Calling multiple DownloadFileAsync at the same time block UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, webclient

I'm making a WPF application where i use WebClient to download files from a webserver. My code right now download one file at a time and wait for that file to complete before starting the next and so on. 
I have several list where the name of the files are stored - like a folder. When i click the first button the downloading starts downloading the files in the first folder seqeuncy, but when the first downloading is in progress and i want to start downloading from second folder by clicking the second button my application freezes. I want my application to run multiple DownloadFileAsync at the same time.
I have tried to start a new thread for each donwloading, but that doens't seems to work either.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        DownloadGameFile dlg = new DownloadGameFile();
        dlg.StartDownload(11825);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadGameFile dlg = new DownloadGameFile();
        dlg.StartDownload(11198);
    }
}
```

---

```
class DownloadGameFile
{
    private DownloadTorrentFile DLTorrent;

    //List of file that already exist
    private List<string> ExistFile = new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo fileInfo;

    private string savePath = @"C:somewhere";
    public string path { get; set; }

    private bool isDelete = false;
    public DownloadGameFile()
    {
        DLTorrent = new DownloadTorrentFile();

    }
    public async void StartDownload(int torrentId)
    {
        try
        {
            DLTorrent.DecodeTorrent(torrentId);

            //Creates a folder to the game
            var newdic = Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath + torrentId);

            fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(savePath + torrentId);
            //File info from a Directory
            FileInfo[] files = fileInfo.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo i in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Files exit " + i);
                if (DLTorrent.GameInfomation[i.Name] != i.Length)
                {
                    i.Delete();
                    isDelete = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("add files ");
                    ExistFile.Add(i.Name);
                }

            }
            //Make a list which file not downloaded yet
            var res = DLTorrent.GameInfomation.Keys.Except(ExistFile);

            var nFiles = files.Length;
            if(nFiles == 0 || !isDelete)
            {
                nFiles++;
                foreach (var x in res)
                {
                    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).label1.Content = nFiles + " out of " + DLTorrent.GameInfomation.Keys.Count();
                    await DownloadProtocol("http://cdn.somewhere/rental/" + torrentId + "/" + x, savePath + torrentId + "/" + x);
                    nFiles++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var x in res)
                {

                    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).label1.Content = nFiles + " out of " + DLTorrent.GameInfomation.Keys.Count();
                    await DownloadProtocol("http://cdn.somewhere/rental/" + torrentId + "/" + x, savePath + torrentId + "/" + x);
                    nFiles++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }


    public async Task DownloadProtocol(string address, string location)
    {

        Uri Uri = new Uri(address);
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived + " " + e.ProgressPercentage);
                ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).DownloadBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            };

            client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Cancelled == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
                }

            };

            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(Uri, location);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I preciate you ae trying to help @sstan. I have change my question with the right code which can compile.

Comment: You cannot use await with webClient.DownloadFileAsync(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991194/c-sharp-download-speed-asynchronously/31994067#31994067

Comment: @alexm i don't see anywhere `DownloadFileAsync` ? What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @alexm, but I tried to copy your WebClientExtensions class and changing to await client.DownloadFileAwaitableAsync(Uri, location, CancellationToken.None);. But it stil freeze my application when I click button1 after i just started by clicking StartDownload_button. It freeze for a while and then it unfreeze and continue the download, but the call from StartDownload_button still download in the background.

Comment: It is right what @Eser says. I'm using DownloadFileTaskAsync.

Comment: @LocDaiLe You you try your code by commenting out `((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).DownloadBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;` in `DownloadProtocol` ?

Comment: Yes @Eser, but that does only show my progressbar?

Comment: @LocDaiLe Does your UI freeze? For ex, when you try to move it on desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DownloadGameFile dlg = new DownloadGameFile();
    await dlg.StartDownload(11825);
}
```

`dlg.StartDownload` must return a Task then.